# How to query by item existance in array on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays but I still couldn't figure out how it solves the issue of querying not-hardcoded user-generated items in array.

Let's say I have a Party collection:

```
Party {
  name: "Birthday party",
  invitees: [56448, 869987, 230232, 202030] # user id's of invited people
}
```

How can I query only parties where I'm in the invitees array without making an index for each possible ID?

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

> Limitations
>   The solution shown above is a great way to simulate array-like structures in Cloud Firestore, but you should be aware of the following limitations:
>
> Indexing limits - A single document can have only 20,000 properties in order to use Cloud Firestore built-in indexes. If your array-like data structure grows to tens of thousands of members, you may run into this limit.

So the short answer is no.

If I were using Firebase Database, I would create a cloud function to watch the `party/invitees` branch on creation and modification, then propagate the invitation to a branch on the userID profile.  Because you can be invited and uninvited, the changeset contains old and new and you can remove invitations from people who are in the `previous` but not in the `next`.

I haven't explored Cloud Functions for Firestore (yet) but I suspect that you can do something similar.

Comment: The problem i see is that I'd have to create an index for each possible ID this way, am i wrong?

Comment: Who is running the query, the user? Wouldn't the user have his or her ID?

Comment: Yes the user does - but Firestore needs you to create a composite index beforehand for each field you want to query (where) by . `.where('invitees.56448', '==', true)` would require an index called `invitees.56448`, this would be very impractical to have an index for each user

Comment: Ok, I see.  Hang on.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the method described in the documentation you point to (i.e. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) and instead of storing the users in an array you save an object like

```
Party {
  name: "Birthday party",
  invitees: {
        "56448": true,
        "869987": true,
        "230232": true,
        .....
       }
}
```

you will be able to query like

```
var yourUserID = .....;  //e.g. '869987'
db.collection('invitees')
    .where('invitees.' + yourUserID, '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(() => {
        // ...
    });
```

And as the doc says "This technique relies on the fact that **Cloud Firestore creates built-in indexes** for all document fields, even fields in a nested map.", so no worries for maintaining the indexes.